# why does my <a> tag keep offsetting my button?

Tags: html, css

I want my button to download a file - I have acheived that by doing the following:

My button:

```
  <button type="button" class="button" id="b3">
     <span class="button__text">DOWNLOAD</span>
     <span class="button__icon">
        <ion-icon name="cloud-download-outline"></ion-icon>
     </span>
  </button>
```

I then wrap it in the `<a>` tag so it downloads a file:

```
<a href="assets/instructions.docx" download>
  <button type="button" class="button" id="b3">
     <span class="button__text">DOWNLOAD</span>
     <span class="button__icon">
        <ion-icon name="cloud-download-outline"></ion-icon>
     </span>
  </button>
</a>
```

This is functionally perfect , exept it offsets mybutton to the right for no apparent reason , here is how i align/position my button:

```
.grid2{
    position: relative;
    height: 469px;
    background-color:#E53935 ;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
  
  }
```

Comment: Why did you add a <a> tag? I think you’re confusing some concepts here. Think a button is something to execute an action in the page. A link "<a> tag" is used to navigate between pages. HTML elements have their own responsibilities. There's no need to include a button inside a link.

Comment: I wrapped a button in an <a> tag - so when the button is  pressed it downloads the file that the tag points to

Comment: Remove the button tag and only use anchor tag in this case, just move the button content into the anchor. Please provide enough code to reproduce the issue, use the snippet button to create a snippet

Comment: You can (and should) style your anchor to look like a button

Comment: Links cannot contain buttons and vice versa. The previous comments are correct [Links are not buttons](https://karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans)

Comment: While you should not use a button in an a element (or vice versa) your original question hasn't been answered, but looking at the code you have provided I can't see that you are styling  the button with grid2 anywhere. Could you provide a working snippet which shows the problem see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.